# Finding $a>1$ such that $\int_0^\pi \tfrac{\sin x\,\mathrm{d}x} { \sqrt{1 − 2a\cos x + a^2}}$ equals given constant

Tags: calculus, integration, legendre-polynomials

$a > 1$, solve for $a$:

$$\int_0^\pi \frac{\sin(x)} { (1 − 2a\cos(x) + a^2)^{1/2}} dx = 0.2018$$

I have attempted to use substitution $u = -\cos x$, $\frac{du}{dx} = \sin x$, limits $[1, -1]$.

I end up with $\frac{1}{a}(1 + 2a + a^2)^{1/2} - \frac{1}{a}(1 - 2a + a^2)^{1/2}  = 0.2018$.

I believe this is not the right direction. I would greatly appreciate any ideas on how to solve this.

Comment: Is is it possible that you meant the integral $\int_0^{\pi}\frac{\sin x\,\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{1-2a\cos x +a^2}}$?

Comment: Yes, I meant a^2. Sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 7):

Let us consider your integral:
$$I=\int_0^\pi \frac{\sin(x)} { (1 − 2a\cos(x) + a^2)^{1/2}}dx,\;\ a>1.$$
Consider a triangle $ABC$ with angles $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ opposite to the sides $a,b,c$, respectively:

[image]

The law of cosines states that
$$c^2=a^2+b^2-2ab\cos(\gamma).$$
To keep with this notation, let $b=1$ and $\gamma=x$.

Our integral becomes:
$$I=\int_0^\pi \frac{\sin(\gamma)} {c}d\gamma.$$
The law of sines states that
$$\frac{\sin(\alpha)}{a}=\frac{\sin(\gamma)}{c}.$$
Our integral becomes:
$$I=\int_0^\pi \frac{\sin(\alpha)}{a}d\gamma.$$

The three angles $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ add up to $\pi$ radians.

Let
$$\gamma=\pi-\alpha-\beta,$$
such that
$$d\gamma=-d\alpha-d\beta.$$
When 
$$\gamma\rightarrow 0,\;\ \alpha\rightarrow \pi,\;\ \beta\rightarrow 0.$$
When
$$\gamma\rightarrow \pi,\;\ \alpha\rightarrow 0,\;\ \beta\rightarrow 0.$$
Our integral becomes:
$$I=\int_\pi^0 \frac{\sin(\alpha)}{a}(-d\alpha)+\int_0^0 \frac{\sin(\alpha)}{a}(-d\beta).$$
Regarding the integral with respect to $\alpha$, incorporate the a minus sign into the integral in order to switch the interval. Recognize that the integral with respect to $\beta$ is equal to zero:
$$I=\int_0^\pi \frac{\sin(\alpha)}{a}d\alpha.$$
Integration yields:
$$I=-\frac{\cos(\alpha)}{a}\bigg |_0^\pi.$$
Evaluating yields:
$$I=\frac{2}{a}.$$
It follows that
$$\frac{2}{a}=0.2018.$$
Therefore,
$$a=\frac{2}{0.2018}=\frac{10000}{1009}.$$

Comment: this is a very elegant solution, thank you.

Comment: (+1) for originality.  But it seems easier to simply enforce the substitution $u=\cos(x)$.

Comment: The term $1-2a\cos(x)+a^2$ immediately reminded me of the law of cosines, leading to this approach.

Answer (score 2):

If the term in the denominator is $a^{2}$ not $x^{2}$, Your answer appears to be correct. Just go further:
$$\frac{\lvert{a+1}\rvert}{a}-\frac{\lvert{a-1}\rvert}{a}=0.2018$$
since $a>1$:
$$\frac{2}{a}=0.2018\\
a = \frac{2}{0.2018}$$

Comment: Yes, it is a^2, it was a typo. Your answer helped a lot, thank you

Comment: Side question: May I ask why there are impossible solutions such as 2=0.2018? Throughout the calculation, i did not square both sides of the equation or anything like that.